# Which ARM command is influencing the SP position?

Tags: arm, stack, pointer, offset

I do static analysis of ARM assembly code (I can't debug it).

When I look on argument that in `SP+0x<SomeOffset>` I can find what I'm looking for, but if I look a few lines further down I see that this argument is not there.

Which ARM, command is influencing the stack pointer (SP) position?

I don't see any add/sub to `SP`, the only commands that I see is `ldr` and `str` from `SP` and to `SP` +function `BL` that not touch on this argument.

I think that even I call to function, when I finish it the `SP` need to be same,  and store to `SP+offset` or load from `SP+offset` don't need to change the `SP`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific stack pointer register in ARM. By convention `R13` is used as the stack pointer. There is no specific push and pop style stack pointer operands either.

Pushing and popping from the stack is carried out using the `STM` (store to memory) and `LDM` (load from memory) operands. These operands can be modified with the post fixes `IA` and `DB`. `IA` is increment after, and `DB` is decrement before.

So `STMDB` means store to memory, decrementing before the store. I.e. pushing on to a full descending stack. The inverse of this would be `LDMIA` which is popping from a full descending stack.

Alternatively you can have `STMIA` and `LDMDB` which means pushing and popping on to and off of an empty ascending stack.

`FD` is the synonym for full descending and `EA` is the synonym for empty ascending. So `STMDB` and `STMFD` are the same. `LDMIA`, `LDMFD` are the same. And so on...

So a full instruction would be for example...

```
STMDB R13!, {R0 - R3}
```

Which means push `R0`, then `R1`, then `R2` and then `R3` on to a full descending stack using `R13` as the stack point. The address being written too is updated for each registered pushed. The `!` means write back and means that `R13` is updated with the final address so it can be used again.

`BL` (branch with link) does NOT affect the stack or the stack pointer. It merely copies the current `PC` (`R15`) in to link (`R14`) before the jump. A simple...

```
MOV R14, R15
```

... will return you back to the original address. However many may pop link straight in to PC at the end of a subroutine. For example...

```
.my_sub_routine
STMFD R13!, {R0, R1, R14}
// Do stuff
LDMFD R13!, {R0, R1, R15} // pop link straight in to PC meaning return.
```

Comment: in fact the newer ARM architectures do standardize R13 as SP, and STMFD/ LDMFD  instructions using it as PUSH/POP.

Comment: Moreover on most of the Cortex series cores, R13 (or SP) is an alias for one of two hardware-managed stack pointers, MSP or PSP, depending on mode and settings.  Things like interrupt requests cause automatic pushes to the active stack too.  R13 is very much a stack pointer on modern(ish) ARM architectures, and not just by convention.